# Increment the sequence when the lines start with specific value in Unix

Tags: shell-script

I want to increment when the line starting has a fixed word else continue with the same number.

Input :

```
CH,A11R,Q9Y5X3,SNX5  
CD,A12L,Q9Y316,MEMO1  
CD,A12L,Q70CQ2,USP34  
CT,A12L,Q8N7H5,PAF1   
CH,A12L,Q8IZL8,PELP1  
CD,A13L,Q5SY16,NOL9   
CD,A13L,Q6P1J9,CDC73  
CT,A13L,Q8WVC0,LEO1   
CH,A13L,Q9Y4W2,LAS1L  
CD,A13L,Q6PD62,CTR9
```

when the first column starts with CH then continue with next number else print the same number

Output :

```
CH,A11R,Q9Y5X3,SNX5  ,1  
CD,A12L,Q9Y316,MEMO1 ,1  
CD,A12L,Q70CQ2,USP34 ,1  
CT,A12L,Q8N7H5,PAF1  ,1  
CH,A12L,Q8IZL8,PELP1 ,2  
CD,A13L,Q5SY16,NOL9  ,2  
CD,A13L,Q6P1J9,CDC73 ,2  
CT,A13L,Q8WVC0,LEO1  ,2  
CH,A13L,Q9Y4W2,LAS1L ,3  
CD,A13L,Q6PD62,CTR9  ,3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With (any) `awk`, a must have in the toolchest:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$1=="CH"{lc++}{print $0,lc}' file
```

same command, but more understandable as multilines decomposed:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}  # set input and output fields separator as ","
    $1=="CH"{lc++}     # if $1(first column)==CH, increment lc (last column)
    {print $0,lc}      # print current line and the variable lc
' file
```

If you need the output *as-is*:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$1=="CH"{lc++}{printf("%-20s,%d\n", $0,lc)}' file
```

```
CH,A11R,Q9Y5X3,SNX5 ,1
CD,A12L,Q9Y316,MEMO1,1
CD,A12L,Q70CQ2,USP34,1
CT,A12L,Q8N7H5,PAF1 ,1
CH,A12L,Q8IZL8,PELP1,2
CD,A13L,Q5SY16,NOL9 ,2
CD,A13L,Q6P1J9,CDC73,2
CT,A13L,Q8WVC0,LEO1 ,2
CH,A13L,Q9Y4W2,LAS1L,3
CD,A13L,Q6PD62,CTR9 ,3
```